# Problemas de diseño de fieldset y form con css html y js

Tags: javascript, html, css, diseño

tengo mi proyecto y tengo en él una vista de respuestas donde muestro diferentes secuencias y cada secuencia se muestra en un form diferente, cada form con tres fieldsets, aquí el código del html:

```
!doctype html>

<head>
     <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>  
     <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/respuestas.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
     <script src="/js/respuestas.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="module"></script>
</head>


@foreach ($secuencias as $secuencia)
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" action="/respuesta" method="POST">
   <!-- progressbar -->
   <ul id="progressbar">
       <li class="active">Secuencias</li>
       <li>Te / Tr / Ti</li>
       <li>Detalles extra</li> 
   </ul>
   <!-- fieldsets -->
   <fieldset>
       <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencia->nombre }}</h3>
       <input type="text" name="plano" placeholder="Plano" />
       <input type="text" name="tipoSecuencia" placeholder="Tipo de Secuencia" />
       <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
       <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencia->nombre }}</h3>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Te </h3>
       <select class="select" name="te" id="te">
          <option value="1,2">1,2</option>
          <option value="1,5">1,5</option>
          <option value="1,45">1,45</option>
       </select>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tr </h3>
       <select class="select" name="tr" id="tr">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="1,2">1,2</option>
       </select>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Ti </h3>
       <select class="select" name="ti" id="ti">
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="750">750</option>
       </select>
       <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" />
       <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
       <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
       <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencia->nombre }}</h3>
       <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Finalizar" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
@endforeach
```

No se si tiene mucho que ver el html pero igual y lo incluyo
esta vista esta llamando al css que es el siguiente:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/

    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/

    background-image: url(/img/resonador.jpg); 
    background-size: cover; 

}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;

}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 50%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
#msform .select {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
 /*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
```

Y el js encargado de la accion del boton de next, previous y submit es:

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

//de-activate current step on progressbar
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

//show the previous fieldset
previous_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'left': left});
        previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

EN FIN, que lo que ocurre es que estoy en la vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me muestra todos los forms necesarios y cada form tiene sus 3 fieldset, hasta aquí todo bien, al darle en siguiente en un form:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien, me muestra el segundo fieldset, pero al darle en el botón de anterior, el form de abajo se encima en el que estoy trabajando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y realmente no sé qué hacer. tengo muy poca idea sobre diseño y la cuestión del css y js mi conocimiento es casi nulo y no sé cómo arreglarlo

Comment: Estás repitiendo ID para cada formulario y barra de progreso. Los ID deben ser únicos.

Comment: como te dicen el id debe ser único y al aplicarle foreach se repite en el bucle y probablemente interfiera con algun estilo como #msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}.

Comment: El detalle es que cada caso tiene diferentes secuencias y creando un form para cada secuencia fue la mejor respuesta a la que pude llegar jajaja creo que tendre que desechar esto y buscar alguna otra forma :(   gracias